# How to inverse a conditional in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a function that changes the case of some text and returns it, based on the value of `capitalisation`. I would like to pass another parameter called `inverse`, which if true, basically performs the opposite; so if `capitalisation` is lowercase, it will make the text lower case instead of uppercase.

It's important that the value of `capitalisation` does not change, because it's used by other parts of the application.

I'm looking for a really succinct way to do this with minimal code.

```
       capitalisation = "lowercase";

       function switchCase(text, inverse) {
            if (capitalisation === "lowercase") {
                text = text.toLowerCase();
            } else {
                text = text.toUpperCase();
            }
            return text;
        }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: @Gonzalo.- That won't work. If `inverse` is false then text is ALWAYS uppercase regardless of capitalisation.

Comment: @Gonzalo.- What you want is `^^` or `XOR` but such an operator is not available in js. You can implement XOR as `(a && !b) || (!a && b)` though

Comment: @DegenSharew - The accepted answer is not the same logic as your answer.

Comment: *so if capitalisation is lowercase, it will make the text lower case instead of uppercase.* Is that what you meant to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In boolean algebra, to invert a logic based on another logical condition you'd use the XOR operator. This is because the truth table is:

```
a       b       result
true    false   true
false   false   false
true    true    false
false   true    true
```

Notice that if we rename b as inverse:

```
a       inverse      result
true    not_inverse  same_as_a
false   not_inverse  same_as_a
true    inverse      opposite_of_a
false   inverse      opposite_of_a
```

So what you want is:

```
if ((capitalisation === "lowercase")  XOR  inverse) ...
```

Unfortunately javascript does not have a logical XOR operator, only a bitwise `^` operator. However, it's easy to implement XOR as `(a && !b) || (!a && b)`. This gives us:

```
if (((capitalisation === "lowercase") && !inverse) ||
    ((capitalisation !== "lowercase") && inverse)) ...
```

Comment: Answer accepted as the most succinct and good supporting information.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
 var CAPITALISATION_LOWERCASE = "lowercase"
 var CAPITALISATION_UPPERCASE = "uppercase"

 capitalisation = "lowercase";

       function switchCase(text, inverse) {
            if (CAPITALISATION_LOWERCASE == capitalisation && inverse) {
                text = text.toUpperCase();
            } else {
                text = text.toLowerCase();
            }
            return text;
        }
```

Comment: This does not work. Same problem with all other answers

Comment: @NielsSteenbeek: I tend to write long explanations for my answers so I was writing when you commented

Comment: Hey guys!! but this is my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

if I understand well:

```
    var capitalisation = "lowercase";
    var inverse = false;

   function switchCase(text, inverse) {
        if (capitalisation === "lowercase") {
            text = text.toLowerCase();
        } else {
            text = text.toUpperCase();
        }
        return text;
    }


   function switchCase2(text, inverse) {
        return inverse ? text.toLowerCase() : text.toUpperCase() ;
    }

    alert(switchCase2('GGFGFF',inverse));
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xg3arot8/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be useful for you. I can show you two ways: with two functions or on only one function:

### 2 functions

```
   capitalisation = "lowercase";

   function switchCase(text, inverse) {
        if(inverse) {
            return switchInverseCase(text);
        }
        if (capitalisation === "lowercase") {
            text = text.toLowerCase();
        } else {
            text = text.toUpperCase();
        }
        return text;
    }

   function switchInverseCase(text) {
        if (capitalisation === "lowercase") {
            text = text.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            text = text.toLowerCase();
        }
        return text;
    }
```

### 1 function

```
   capitalisation = "lowercase";

   function switchCase(text, inverse) {

        if (capitalisation === "lowercase") {
            if(inverse) {
                text = text.toUpperCase();
            } else {
                text = text.toLowerCase();
            }
        } else {
            if(inverse) {
                text = text.toLowerCase();
            } else {
                text = text.toUpperCase();
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: why are you saying if(inverse) on the second function if(inverse) is always true at that point.

Comment: `inverse` is a parameter, it will be true or false depending on the value of this argument. I don't catch your point, @DegenSharew

Comment: you have ```if(inverse) {
            return switchInverseCase(text);
        }``` on the first function that means ```switchInverseCase``` will be called only if inverse is true.

Comment: Yeah, that's the OP's requirement. Only reverse the returned value if `inverse` is true.

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the fact that JS treats functions as first class citizens and store in a dictionary the functions to apply to the string. Then just retrieve the correct function depending on the value of `capitalisation` and `inverse`.

```js
var capitalisation = "lowercase";

function switchCase(text, inverse) {
  var strProto = String.prototype,
    inverseType = function(capitalisation) {
      return capitalisation === "lowercase" ? "uppercase" : "lowercase";
    },
    fncDict = {
      "uppercase": strProto.toUpperCase,
      "lowercase": strProto.toLowerCase
    };

  return inverse ? fncDict[inverseType(capitalisation)].apply(text) : fncDict[capitalisation].apply(text);
}

console.log(switchCase("ASDF", false));
console.log(switchCase("ASDF", true));
```